# New user, new install, Wifi doesn't work

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04, broadcom

Brand new to Ubuntu/Linux. Trying to get HP Mini netbook working better. It was unusable with Windows 7 (too slow).

So far it flies with Ubuntu, but no WiFi. I can see all the WiFi connections from my home, the neighbors, etc. I believe it connected briefly during installation, but I can't get it to connect now.

This is a clean install. The WiFi for all other home devices is working fine. Network specs are below. One of the moderators said it *should* work. The wired interface is working great, BTW.

Thank you in advance for your help

Machine is HP Mini 110. Ubuntu version is 13.04. Would I have better luck with 12.04?

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E 
  PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:148a]
Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless 
  LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:145c]
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! What do you mean by *a moderator said...*?

Comment: Have you tried checking if your wifi is being either hard or soft-blocked by any chance?
If not then type 'rfkill list all'

Comment: Sorry, copied from another forum that had a response from a moderator.  This worked, by the way:                                        sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo modprobe brcmsmac

Answer (score 2):

This should get your wireless working.

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

Comment: This answer is specific to 13.04.